# Issue with merging changes between two features branches

Tags: git

I have two branches as follows:

feature/base1
feature/base2

The feature/base2 branch is created from feature/base1.

1. I introduced a couple of new files, namely a.xml and b.xml, along with some modifications to an existing file named p.yaml.
2. I merged the changes from feature/base2 into feature/base1.
3. Subsequently, I deleted a.xml and b.xml, and reverted the changes made to the p.yaml file after realizing that we do not want to maintain those modifications with feature/base1.
4. In addition to the aforementioned changes, I incorporated a few more modifications to feature/base1.
5. To integrate the changes from feature/base1 added in step 4, I attempted to perform a merge using the command git merge feature/base1 from the feature/base2 branch. However, I observed that the merge was deleting a.xml and b.xml, and also reverting the changes made to p.yaml.

I experimented with various approaches but have not been successful in resolving this issue. I am seeking guidance on how to absorb the changes added to feature/base1 in step 4 only.

Comment: Step 5 references changes "added in step 5".  Is that supposed to be "added in step 3" or "added in step 4"?  Are the changes in step 3 applied to feature/base1 or feature/base2?

Comment: I applied changes to feature/base1 as part of step:3

Comment: By merging a branch you express "I want all the changes that were introduced on that branch since it diverged from this branch". There is no way to be selective. When you merge base1 back to base2, you get everything that was done on that branch. The only way out is to plan your changes better and separate them into branches in a more desirable way. When you merge the branches back in forth like you did, it is essentially is if you worked on just one branch, not two branches, and on one branch you can't both have and not have a file.

Comment: "we do not want to maintain those modifications with feature/base1" <-- this does not sound like a "feature" branch, this sounds more like a branch created to serve a specific customer, aka a long-lived branch. If it is truly a feature branch, eventually both of these feature branches will be merged back into your main branch, in which case all those changes will be merged together. Was it really a problem for the branch that those changes were present? Or did you just not understand how git merging works and thought they were not necessary?

Comment: does [`cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) against `feature/base1` changes on step 4 useful? tbh, the way you used git is not exactly stellar. it would be best to have a piece meal commits and have `features` that lives independent of each other whenever possible.

Comment: You could rebase your base2 branch on top of base1 branch, that way all changes made in base2 will be replayed on top of base1, and you will have your changes. The downside is that it rewrite the base2 history but keeps base1 history clean